# Iterate through a nested json object array in the render (ReactJS)

Tags: json, reactjs

I'm trying to iterate and display certain values of a JSON on my web application using ReactJS.

My render looks like this:

```
render() {

  const orders = 
  Object.keys(this.state.data).map((e,i) => {
   return (
     <div key = {i}>
       <div>ID: {this.state.data[e].id}</div>
       <div>Email: {this.state.data[e].email}</div>
       <div>Note: {this.state.data[e].note}</div>
       <div>{this.findValue(e)}</div>
     </div>
   )
 })

 return (
   <div>
     <div>
       {orders}
     </div>
   </div>
 );
}
```

Now everything looks fine until I run this.findValue where it immediately returns after the first iteration instead of returning multiple divs.

```
findValue = (e) => {
    for(let key2 in this.state.data[e].line_items) {    
        return (
          <div>
            Line item: {this.state.data[e].line_items[key2].title}
         </div>
        )
   }
```

How would I be able to return every line item? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you return something from the function given to `map`, you are just returning what the current element should be mapped to in the new array. When you return inside the `for..in`, you are returning from the `findValue` method instead.

You could use `map` on the array of keys in `line_items` as well.

```
findValue = e => {
  const { line_items } = this.state.data[e];
  return Object.keys(line_items).map(key => (
    <div key={key}>Line item: {line_items[key].title}</div>
  ));
};
```